# Is original bitcoin program needed with multibit?

Tags: blockchain, multibit

I have only MultiBit installed. Is this enough, or do I have to install the original bitcoin program to download the blockchain?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the original Bitcoin QT progam installed to use MultiBit.